# How to get tap position in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently using `DragGesture` to track the position of an active touch within a SwiftUI view. This approach is working as expected, but I also want to capture the initial position of the touch. I looked at `TapGesture` and `LongPressGesture`, however these seem to just return boolean values. How do I get the initial touch position on a SwiftUI View?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($dragAmount) { currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentState.translation
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .gesture(dragGesture)
            Text(dragAmount.debugDescription)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `SpatialTapGesture`

see also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spatialtapgesture

For example:

```
.highPriorityGesture(
    SpatialTapGesture()
        .onEnded { loc in
            print("---> loc: \(loc)")
        })
```

Also works for me using:

```
.onTapGesture { tap in
    print("---> tap: \(tap)")
}
```

EDIT-1:

You can also use a different approach without using an initial `TapGesture`, such as this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    @State var firstLoc: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.1)
            .updating($dragAmount) { currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentState.translation
                if firstLoc == .zero {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        firstLoc = CGPoint(x: dragAmount.width, y: dragAmount.height)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                firstLoc = .zero
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle().foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .gesture(dragGesture)
            Text(dragAmount.debugDescription).foregroundStyle(.white)
            
            Text(firstLoc.debugDescription).foregroundStyle(.white).offset(y: 77)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-2

to `capture` the touch location immediately as you tap the screen, try this using `onChanged`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    @State var firstLoc: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0) // <--- here
            .onChanged { value in
                if firstLoc != value.startLocation {  // <--- here
                    firstLoc = value.startLocation
                }
            }
            .updating($dragAmount) { currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentState.translation
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                firstLoc = .zero
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle().foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .gesture(dragGesture)
            Text(dragAmount.debugDescription).foregroundStyle(.white)
            
            Text(firstLoc.debugDescription).foregroundStyle(.white).offset(y: 77)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these ideas! So I want to get the location and soon as the users touches the view. `SpatialTapGesture` is the idea, but seems to only give you the location on a touchUpInside event. The problem with DragGesture too is that it only starts reporting once you start moving the touch.

Comment: Ok, I see. Updated my answer with another possible approach (EDIT-2)